# MAX232 chip by TI not functioning correctly?

Tags: rs232

I'm trying to use this to convert rs232 levels from my gsm modem to 5v TTL. I was struggling to get it working. So I devised a test to see if I even got any form of communications. My custom Arduino is based on  duemilanove design hence it uses [ft232rl](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf). I've unplugged my arduino chip. Now I'm just using the ft232rl ttl pins which are connected to max232. I've connected the T1OUT to R1IN. My theory is I can create a loop back so I should get back whatever I send using the terminal within arduino IDE. I've double quaduple checked my connections using sparkfun and various other sites. But nothing happens. Why?

I get 8.5v on  pin2 and -7.5 on pin 6 and according to the datasheet thats within spec. I've powered it using 5v. I've decoupled the VCC.

If you could come up with some common pitfalls with this chip, I will be extremely grateful. Btw I don't have a rs232 port on my pc.

[image]

Comment: Schematic of your wiring please.

Comment: The MAX232 needs more then just Vcc decoupling caps, IIRC. Do you have the caps for the flying-capacitor voltage converter as well? (1 uF between pins 1&3, 1 uF between pins 4&5, and 1 uF to ground on both pins 2 and 6)

Comment: I didn't have enough 1uf but all the caps I've used are at least 1uf

Comment: When you connect the FT232 TTL pins, does the loopback work as you expect? (BTW, the C on V- is connectyed the wrong way round, but that is unlikely to be your problem.)

Comment: Capacitor at pin 6 must be connected the other way round: positive terminal (+) at GND!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry there was two issues with what I was doing.
the breadboard wire used on the TX pin was broken. it looked good as new. must of strained it lol.  also I connected it to where.the atmega was hence the TX and rx was the wrong. way round. which is how I discovered the breadboard wire was dodgy.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your whole question, but two very obvious problems exhibited by the schematic are that neither power nor ground are connected to the chip.

You can see a example of where I used a similar chip in a real product at http://www.embedinc.com/products/rslink2.  Go down to the documentation section to see the schematic.